# UIApplication's sendAction() works even if target(forAction:…) is nil

Tags: ios, uikit, first-responder, uiresponder

This code is called when a subview (`imageSlideshow`) is tapped:

```
        imageSlideshow.didTap = { [weak self] in
        guard UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(ImageCarouselViewResponder.didTapImageCarousel(sender:)), to: nil, from: self, for: nil) else {
            assertionFailure("No target for ImageCarouselViewResponder.didTapImageCarousel(sender:)")
            return
        }
        …
```

This works as expected, as you can see from this debugging output:

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(ImageCarouselViewResponder.didTapImageCarousel(sender:)), to: nil, from: self, for: nil) 
true
```

However, when I try to ask for the target with the same selector, it's `nil`:

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.target(forAction: #selector(ImageCarouselViewResponder.didTapImageCarousel(sender:)), withSender: self)
nil
```

Furthermore, I've added an extension to walk the responder tree to find the first responder, and it returns `nil` in this situation.

How is `sendAction(…)` working if there is no first responder?

Comment: Have you seen this page in the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html)?

Comment: So the document says the system makes the item underneath the event the first responder, but if that's the case, I still don't see why `target(forAction:)` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`target(forAction:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621146-target) will only pass the request up the responder chain *from that responder*, but the only thing [after the application in the responder chain is the application delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621146-target). Unless this method is implemented in either of those two, calling `target(forAction:)` on the application instance would return `nil`.

Calling [`sendAction(_:to:from:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622946-sendaction) with a `nil` target works because it sends the message to the *first responder* which passes it up the responder chain until it is handled.

Comment: I am not sure that he has a first responder in his view hierarchy. The method sendAction(_:to:from:for:) worked because he has set a sender object. This method , will try to find out the first responder. If the first responder has been found then will send an action to it. If the first responder is not present then will try to send an action starting from the sender object.